# HTML - How to apply padding to a horizontal border?

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML newsletter table, to structure the content I want horizontal borders. Somehow the horizontal borders always have 100% width according to the table width. How can I achieve 20px padding to the left and right of it?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93QEh/1/)

HTML

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="400">         
<tr>
    <td >Banana
    </td>
</tr> 
<tr style=" padding: 0 20px 0 20px;">
    <td style=" padding: 0 20px 0 20px; border-bottom: 3px solid red;">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td >Apple
    </td>
</tr>    
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't able to do what you want in current code

you need to do some trick 
see this

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="400">         
    <tr>
        <td >Banana
        </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr >
        <td> <hr  style=" border:0px; margin: 0 20px 0 20px; border-bottom: 3px solid red;">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >Apple
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

i have used (HR) tag in 2nd table row, this will solve your problem ☺

Comment: I tested your code, but in msn email clients it is back to 100%

Comment: @vuvu add (!important) in with margin property
like this ( margin: 0 20px 0 20px !important; )
try it and let me know

Answer (score 0):

A border does not take padding into account, but it does with margin. See the [CSS Box Modell](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

On CSS, there is the cascade. It parses top-dowmn and specific overrides general

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve what you want (including ways in which we have to change the HTML code). Suppose you want to keep the table layout. You can just set the `border-left` and `border-right` of the middle `td` like this:

```
tr.hr > td {
  border:none;
  border-left:20px solid white;
  border-right:20px solid white;    
  background:red;
  height:3px;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<tr> <td> Banana </td> </tr> 
<tr class='hr'> <td></td></tr>
<tr> <td> Apple </td> </tr>
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/93QEh/5/)

Note that the color of `border-left` and `border-right` should be the same to the background color of your table. (they are all `white` in the demo).

Answer (score 0):

1. Please have a look at the HTML email boilerplate.
   http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/#f1
2. Limitations using CSS: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/. It solves may issues with ie. spacing amongst others and email clients rendering issues (Gmail, Outlook,Yahoo, ...)
3. HTML emails need to respect 600px width as it is a default for the preview.
4. To test the HTML email (if no mail configured on a testing server) you could use http://putsmail.com/ Check also on smart phone as many people tend to read mail on it

You can achieve the effect using a combination of 3 cells where the first and last use spacers and the middle can be a red solid color gif.

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="20"><img width="20" height="3" src="transparent.gif" alt="" /></td>
            <td valign="top" width="560">
                <img src="red.gif" width="560" height="3" alt="" />
            </td>
            <td valign="top" width="20"><img width="20" height="3" src="transparent.gif" alt="" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```